# SQL Pivot Table Grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, pivot

I have a table as follows:

```
Date        Ticket  Question    Response
2016-10-01  1       Score?      10
2016-10-01  1       Reason?     Awesome
2016-10-02  2       Score?      9
2016-10-02  2       Reason?     Good
2016-10-03  3       Score?      8
2016-10-03  3       Reason?     Okay
```

I want to Pivot it in SQL as:

```
Date        Ticket  Score?  Reason?
2016-10-01  1       10      Awesome
2016-10-02  2       9       Good
2016-10-03  3       8       Okay
```

Can someone please help? I'm happy to provide more details if required.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it does not need to by dynamic, a simple conditional aggregation should do.

```
Select Date
      ,Ticket
      ,Score  = max(case when Question='Score?'  then Response else null end)
      ,Reason = max(case when Question='Reason?' then Response else null end)
 From YourTable
 Group By Date,Ticket
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below using PIVOT:

```
Select * from
(Select * from table) x
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Response) FOR Question IN ([Score?], [Reason?])
) p
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT Date,
       Ticket,
       MAX( CASE WHEN Question = 'Score?' THEN Response END          
           ) AS Score?,
       MAX( CASE WHEN Question = 'Reason' THEN Response END          
           ) AS Reason?,  
  FROM table
GROUP BY Date,Ticket 
;
```