# Trouble with PIVOT in SQL (Azure SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, azure-sql-database

I need to list survey responses in one row. The table of survey responses lists a questionID and a ResponseID (these are multiple choice questions), so one row for each response. There are 12 questions. Things like the date of the response, worker who conducted the survey, and worker who entered the survey are kept in other tables.

So, I have a query that gets the responses for one survey into 12 rows. Now I need to get all that into one row. Pivot, right?

But I could never get it to work. :-( Tried several solutions from this and other fora (including Mickey's documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017).

Then I found this solution, that doesn't use pivot at all, here: [SQL Pivot Table Grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39961847/sql-pivot-table-grouping)

It worked great, but the example has only two questions. Some of our surveys will have over 50 questions, so I'm guessing that won't be a very elegant solution.

So I'm back to my pivot issue.

Experience level is somewhere between idiot and novice, so I'm probably missing something obvious.

Here's the query by itself (works as expected):

```
SELECT AssessmentResponses.ID, AssessmentQuestions.QuestionNumber, 
   AssessmentResponseAnswers.QuestionID,
   AssessmentAnswerChoices.AnswerChoiceNumber 
FROM (AssessmentResponses RIGHT JOIN AssessmentResponseAnswers 
   ON AssessmentResponses.ID = AssessmentResponseAnswers.AssessmentResponseID) 
   LEFT JOIN (AssessmentQuestions RIGHT JOIN AssessmentAnswerChoices 
   ON AssessmentQuestions.ID = AssessmentAnswerChoices.AssessmentQuestionID) 
   ON AssessmentResponseAnswers.AnswerChoiceID = AssessmentAnswerChoices.AnswerChoiceID 
WHERE AssessmentResponses.AssessmentID = 1 AND AssessmentResponses.RespondentID = 44;
```

Here's how I tried to make it pivot:

```
SELECT ID, [1A], [1B], [2A], [2B], [3A], [3B], [4A], [4B], [5A], [5B], [6A], [6B] 
FROM (
SELECT AssessmentResponses.ID, AssessmentQuestions.QuestionNumber, 
   AssessmentResponseAnswers.QuestionID,
   AssessmentAnswerChoices.AnswerChoiceNumber 
FROM (AssessmentResponses RIGHT JOIN AssessmentResponseAnswers 
   ON AssessmentResponses.ID = AssessmentResponseAnswers.AssessmentResponseID) 
   LEFT JOIN (AssessmentQuestions RIGHT JOIN AssessmentAnswerChoices 
   ON AssessmentQuestions.ID = AssessmentAnswerChoices.AssessmentQuestionID)
   ON AssessmentResponseAnswers.AnswerChoiceID = AssessmentAnswerChoices.AnswerChoiceID 
WHERE AssessmentResponses.AssessmentID = 1 AND AssessmentResponses.RespondentID = 44
) AS Src 
PIVOT
(
MAX(AnswerChoiceNumber) 
FOR QuestionNumber IN ([1A], [1B], [2A], [2B], [3A], [3B], [4A], [4B], [5A], [5B], [6A], [6B]) 
)
AS Pvt;
```

I was hoping that would give me 1 row with 13 columns (ID plus the twelve questions). But it gave me still 12 rows: the 13 columns are there, and it just gives null values for 11 of the twelve questions. (In row1, 1A has an answer; in row2, 1B has an answer, etc.)

What am I missing?

Comment: I think you can drop the azure-sql-database tag.  Your issue isn't specific to that.  You may attract other responders, and someone may even write a dynamic sql statement for you that would be even more flexible than my answer, with standard caveats for dynamic SQL, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tweaked your code just a bit to get rid of "QuestionID" in the subquery.  It is not involved in what you're pivoting on, so SQL Server will think it's one of your keys.

```
SELECT ID, [1A], [1B], [2A], [2B], [3A], [3B], [4A], [4B], [5A], [5B], [6A], [6B] 
FROM (
SELECT AssessmentResponses.ID, AssessmentQuestions.QuestionNumber, 
   AssessmentAnswerChoices.AnswerChoiceNumber 
FROM (AssessmentResponses RIGHT JOIN AssessmentResponseAnswers 
   ON AssessmentResponses.ID = AssessmentResponseAnswers.AssessmentResponseID) 
   LEFT JOIN (AssessmentQuestions RIGHT JOIN AssessmentAnswerChoices 
   ON AssessmentQuestions.ID = AssessmentAnswerChoices.AssessmentQuestionID)
   ON AssessmentResponseAnswers.AnswerChoiceID = AssessmentAnswerChoices.AnswerChoiceID 
WHERE AssessmentResponses.AssessmentID = 1 AND AssessmentResponses.RespondentID = 44
) AS Src 
PIVOT
(
MAX(AnswerChoiceNumber) 
FOR QuestionNumber IN ([1A], [1B], [2A], [2B], [3A], [3B], [4A], [4B], [5A], [5B], [6A], [6B]) 
)
AS Pvt;
```

I imagine you're used to the designer.  A few tips (not implemented above) to make code more readable:

- You can usually omit parentheses around your join statements
- I'd re-work your joins to associate one on-statement per join statement
- Aliases!

Comment: Brilliant!! It was "QuestionID" that is removed from your version of the query. As soon as I removed it, I got my desired results.

Thanks so very much!

I'm actually not used to the designer. (Kid you not: what's the designer?) I'm using SSMS. I struggle with joins, so (and I know this is *awful*) I build tables in MS Access, make queries using the designer, then copy the SQL into SSMS and see if it works.

That makes me a hell of a hack, but I'm trying to learn.

Thanks again!

Comment: I worked in SSMS to add aliases, rework the joins, and omit the parentheses. The query still worked. :-) Thanks for the tips.

Comment: Whoops, changed the answer narrative to reflect the right column.  Thanks.  Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this is not exactly a work to do with pivot. Maybe like this:

```
SELECT ar.ID
,(
  SELECT aac.AnswerChoiceNumber
  FROM AssessmentResponseAnswers ara, AssessmentAnswerChoices aac, AssessmentQuestions aq
  WHERE ar.ID=ara.AssessmentResponseID
  AND ara.AnswerChoiceID=aac.AnswerChoiceID
  AND aq.ID=aac.AssessmentQuestionID
  AND aq.QuestionNumber='1A'
 ) 1A
 ,(
  SELECT aac.AnswerChoiceNumber
  FROM AssessmentResponseAnswers ara, AssessmentAnswerChoices aac, AssessmentQuestions aq
  WHERE ar.ID=ara.AssessmentResponseID
  AND ara.AnswerChoiceID=aac.AnswerChoiceID
  AND aq.ID=aac.AssessmentQuestionID
  AND aq.QuestionNumber='1B'
 ) 1B
, (...)
FROM AssessmentResponses ar
WHERE ar.AssessmentID=1 
AND ar.RespondentID=44
```

I was having problems with your usage of the joins but I tried to figure it out - maybe it is correct.

Comment: Bartosz, why don't you fill in the ellipsis as an exercise.   Then imagine OP's requirement that some surveys will have more than 50 questions.  Then imagine making a change to one of the base table names, and having to implement this simple change in your extended queries.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Sorry about my joins; they are indeed rubbish. I tried your code for 1A and 1B and it worked (but I had to put square brackets around them, like this: `) [1A]` ). However, it would be a bit much to have to do all that code for larger surveys. The solution above with the pivot statement nailed it for me.